# Will I Need a transit Visa if I plan to fly through Heathrow UK?

Tags: usa, uk, transit-visas, lhr, lebanese-citizens

I booked a flight to London and another separate ticket to Boston. I have an F4 immigrant visa to the US that expires on June 18. Will I need a transit visa? If y'all can't answer me, who should I call to ask? I need to get my baggage as well.

Comment: Start here: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa . What's your nationality ?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I suppose I'm eligible under this category
: you’re travelling to (or on part of a reasonable journey to) Australia, Canada, New Zealand or the USA and have a valid visa for that country

But is there any way to make sure that I am able to transit without a Visa?

Comment: @Hilmar I did that. I'm Lebanese so I'd need a transit visa technically but it says that I might not be need it if I have a visa to the US.

Comment: The uk.gov visa information pages can be confusing. Whether you'll need a UK transit visa, or a UK visitor in transit visa, or no UK visa at all, will be determined by things like how long your London layover is, and whether you'll change terminals or airports in London. You may get more specific help here if you specify them. If you do, add the info into the text of your question by using the "edit" button.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Is it worth giving heathrow a call to ask them?

Comment: There are so many use cases for international travel, and there's so much likelihood that you won't be able to get to someone who knows, that I wouldn't bother asking the airport. YMMV.

Comment: @dwarfhunter12 “But is there any way to make sure that I am able to transit without a Visa?” No. Even visa holders can be denied entry.